# Configurable map viewer (CMV) - Find the area of drawn polygon

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I am trying to get the area of a polygon and divide that by 16.94 ft^2. 
I have plugged in a  [Template](http://jsfiddle.net/wZjXz/7/) I found. I am missing something. I am trying to get the template and my original code to talk. That way when I draw a polygon the area is outputted along with the original function of finding the average of the point values within.

**UPDATE:**
The error I keep getting is:
 "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefinedmessage: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }**proto**: Error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

```
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
'esri/toolbars/draw',
'esri/InfoTemplate',
'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
'esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol',
'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
'esri/Color',
'esri/tasks/query',
'dijit/form/Button',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/on',
'dojo/_base/array',
'dojo/dom',
'dojo/text!./Select/templates/Select.html',
"esri/graphicsUtils",  
"esri/tasks/GeometryService",
"esri/tasks/AreasAndLengthsParameters",
'xstyle/css!./Select/css/Select.css'  ,
"esri/geometry/Extent",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
           "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/units",
    "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
    "esri/geometry/geodesicUtils",
    "esri/geometry/Polyline",
    "esri/dijit/Scalebar",


    "dojo/json",
    "esri/config",
    "esri/map",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/geometry/Geometry"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Draw, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Query, Button, lang, on, arrayUtil, dom, SelectTemplate, graphicsUtils, GeometryService,AreasAndLengthsParameters, css,Extent, SpatialReference, SimpleFillSymbol, Units, webMercatorUtils, geodesicUtils, Polyline, Scalebar, json, esriConfig, Map, Graphic, Geometry) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        templateString: SelectTemplate,
        selectTools: null,

        postCreate: function () {
            this.selectTools = new Draw(this.map);

            this.selectQuery = new Query();

            on(this.selectTools, "DrawEnd", lang.hitch(this, function (geometry) {
                this.selectTools.deactivate();
                this.selectQuery.geometry = geometry;

                this.featureLayer.selectFeatures(this.selectQuery,
                FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
            }));
this.fieldsSelectionSymbol =
             new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
new Color([0,0,0]), 1),
new Color([0,0,0,0.5]));

            var content = "<b>Status</b>: ${STATUS}" +  
                  "<br><b>Cumulative Gas</b>: ${CUMM_GAS} MCF" +  
                  "<br><b>Total Acres</b>: ${APPROXACRE}" +  
                  "<br><b>Avg. Field Depth</b>: ${AVG_DEPTH} meters";  
    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${grid_code}", content);  

    this.map.on("load", function () {
        var tb = new Draw(map);
        tb.on("selection-complete", lang.hitch(map, getAreaAndLength));
        tb.activate(Draw.FREEHAND_POLYGON);
    });

    var geometryService = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    geometryService.on("selection-complete", outputAreaAndLength);

    function getAreaAndLength(event) {
        var map = this,
            geometry = event.geometry;


        var graphic = map.graphics.add(new Graphic(geometry, new SimpleFillSymbol()));
        var geom = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(geometry);
        var areas = geodesicUtils.geodesicAreas([geom], Units.ACRES);
        var polyline = new Polyline(geom.spatialReference);
        polyline.paths = geom.rings;
        var lengths = geodesicUtils.geodesicLengths([polyline], Units.FEET);
        dom.byId("area").innerHTML = areas[0].toFixed(3) + " acres";
        dom.byId("length").innerHTML = lengths[0].toFixed(3) + " feet";

        //setup the parameters for the areas and lengths operation
        var areasAndLengthParams = new AreasAndLengthsParameters();
        areasAndLengthParams.lengthUnit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_FOOT;
        areasAndLengthParams.areaUnit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_ACRES;
        geometryService.simplify([geometry], function (simplifiedGeometries) {
            areasAndLengthParams.polygons = simplifiedGeometries;
            geometryService.areasAndLengths(areasAndLengthParams);
        });
    }

    function outputAreaAndLength(event) {
        var result = event.result;
        console.log(json.stringify(result));
        dom.byId("area").innerHTML += "<br/>Server: " + result.areas[0].toFixed(3) + " acres";
        dom.byId("length").innerHTML += "<br/>Server: " + result.lengths[0].toFixed(3) + " feet";
    }




            var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(this.title, content);

            this.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(this.featureLayerURL,
            {
                mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,


                infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
                outFields: ["*"]
            });

            this.featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression(this.defExpress);

            this.featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(this.fieldsSelectionSymbol);
            this.featureLayer.on("selection-complete", lang.hitch(this, 'avgGasProduction'));
            var clearMsg = this.clearSelectMsg;
            this.featureLayer.on("selection-clear", function () {
                dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<i>" + clearMsg + "</i>";
            });

            this.map.addLayer(this.featureLayer);

        },

        select: function () {
            this.selectTools.activate(Draw.FREEHAND_POLYGON);
        },
        clearSelection: function () {
            this.featureLayer.clearSelection();
        },




          avgGasProduction: function (event) {
            var productionSum = 0, productionAvg = 0;
            var sumField = this.fieldToSum;

            arrayUtil.forEach(event.features, function (feature) {
                productionSum += feature.attributes[sumField];
            });

            if (event.features && event.features.length > 0) {
                productionAvg = Math.round(productionSum / event.features.length)
            }

              dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<b>" + this.selectSumMsgPrefix + " " + productionAvg + " " + this.selectSumUnits + ". </b>";

          this.map.infoWindow.setTitle("Average Solar Potential")  
                  this.map.infoWindow.setContent("<b>Selected Area Potential: " + productionAvg + " KWh/(m^2). </b>");  
                  var gExt = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(event.features);  
                  this.map.infoWindow.show(gExt.getCenter());  
             dom.byId("area").innerHTML = areas[0].toFixed(3) + " acres";

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: " I am missing something" is not enough information to solicit help. Please reword your question and identify what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't identified where in the code the error is occurring. I am only guessing it has something to do with the polyline since this line in the code does not appear to be correct:

```
var polyline = new Polyline(geom.spatialReference);
```

Perhaps it should be something like this instead?

```
var polyline = new Polyline(geom);
```

Additional thoughts based on new comment:

Th `avgGasProduction` method does not know anything about the `area` variable because is not in scope within that method. You should move that line to `getAreaAndLength` method because that area variable is local to that method.

Yet another additional thought based on yet another new comment:

```
var tb = new Draw(map);
tb.on("selection-complete", lang.hitch(map, getAreaAndLength));
```

The draw toolbar does not have a `selection-complete` event so your `getAreaAndLength` method will never be called. That's the first problem.

I pointed out one other possible issue with this method already. Looking through the code, there may be other issues as well as you move along. I recommend debugging the code by stepping through the lines in Chome's dev tools to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I believe I the error is coming from here:

dom.byId("area").innerHTML = areas[0].toFixed(3) + " acres";
(this is the last line of code)

Comment: I agree that it should not be there. I had it in the getAreaAndLength method but it did not "talk" to the draw function. This is the part I cannot seem to get working.

Comment: you also have two draw toolbars in the code.